# How to increase call stack in chrome ajax call?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

[image]

Is there any way that can I can increase the number of function call, that are shown in the above image?

Right now I am debugging the code and I want to find the origin of the click function, but it is only showing me 9 function call at max and I want to see more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 google-chrome --js-flags="--stack-trace-limit 10000"
```

or

`Error.stackTraceLimit =  Infinity`

Comment: For ```google-chrome --js-flags="--stack-trace-limit 10000"```, where should I put it?